# GPUImagePicture with a GPUImageBuffer target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to do the following to display an image instead of trying to access video when `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` is true.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fake_camera"];

GPUImagePicture *fakeInput = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
GPUImageBuffer *videoBuffer = [[GPUImageBuffer alloc] init];
[fakeInput processImage];
[fakeInput addTarget:videoBuffer];
[videoBuffer addTarget:self.backgroundImageView]; //backgroundImageView is a GPUImageView
```

This renders my `backgroundImageView` in black color without displaying my image.

If I send the output of `fakeInput` to `backgroundImageView` directly, I **see** the picture rendered normally in `backgroundImageView`.

What's going on here?

EDIT:

As Brad recommended I tried:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fake_camera"];

_fakeInput = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
GPUImagePicture *secondFakeInput = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
[_fakeInput processImage];
[secondFakeInput processImage];
[_fakeInput addTarget:_videoBuffer];
[secondFakeInput addTarget:_videoBuffer];
[_videoBuffer addTarget:_backgroundImageView];
```

I also tried:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fake_camera"];

_fakeInput = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
[_fakeInput processImage];
[_fakeInput processImage];
[_fakeInput addTarget:_videoBuffer];
[_videoBuffer addTarget:_backgroundImageView];
```

None of this two approaches seems to work... should they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GPUImageBuffer does as its name suggests, it buffers frames. If you send a still photo to it, that one image is buffered, but is not yet sent out. You'd need to send a second image into it (or use `-processImage` a second time) to get the default buffer of one frame deep to display your original frame.

GPUImageBuffer really doesn't serve any purpose for still images. It's intended as a frame-delaying operation for video in order to do frame-to-frame comparisons, like a low-pass filter. If you need to do frame comparisons of still images, a blend is a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks, this is mostly for running tests so that's more or less the point of it.

Comment: Hey Brad, tried your suggestions (and edited my post). They doesn't seem to solve the issue. Maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Goles - Adding two targets to it won't work, because it only recognizes a single input, so the first approach won't work. For the second, it might recognize that you're only sending the first image a second time, and ignore the second input. Again, the GPUImageBuffer was not built with still image input in mind.